# MySQL Workbench does not generate a database

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

When I try to generate a database using Forward Engineer I get an error like this.

Executing SQL script in server

> ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'VISIBLE,   INDEX `fk_Personal_Human1_idx`
>   (`Human_idMan` ASC) VISIBLE,   CONSTRA' at line 12

SQL Code:

```
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `mydb`.`Personal`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Personal` (
      `idPersonal` INT NOT NULL,
      `Experience` INT NULL,
      `Department_idDepartment` INT NOT NULL,
      `Date_of_accept` DATE NOT NULL,
      `Date_of_release` DATE NULL,
      `Human_idMan` INT NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`idPersonal`),
      INDEX `fk_Personal_Department1_idx` (`Department_idDepartment` ASC) VISIBLE,
      INDEX `fk_Personal_Human1_idx` (`Human_idMan` ASC) VISIBLE,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_Personal_Department1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`Department_idDepartment`)
        REFERENCES `mydb`.`Department` (`idDepartment`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_Personal_Human1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`Human_idMan`)
        REFERENCES `mydb`.`Human` (`idMan`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
```

SQL script execution finished: statements: 7 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch

Comment: Remove the `visible` from the indexes. It is useless anyway. An index is visible by default.

Comment: Just delete all "VISIBLE" constraint and all have worked

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the difference in syntax across different MySQL server versions. **MySQL Workbench 8.0** is auto-generating `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX` statement for the MySQL server **version 8.0**.

**Most likely, your MySQL server version < 8.0.** You can remove `VISIBLE` keyword from your `CREATE TABLE` statement. It will look as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Personal` (
  `idPersonal` INT NOT NULL,
  `Experience` INT NULL,
  `Department_idDepartment` INT NOT NULL,
  `Date_of_accept` DATE NOT NULL,
  `Date_of_release` DATE NULL,
  `Human_idMan` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idPersonal`),
  INDEX `fk_Personal_Department1_idx` (`Department_idDepartment` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Personal_Human1_idx` (`Human_idMan` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Personal_Department1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Department_idDepartment`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Department` (`idDepartment`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Personal_Human1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Human_idMan`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Human` (`idMan`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

---

From the [MySQL Server 8.0 Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html), the syntax for `CREATE INDEX` is:

```
CREATE [UNIQUE | FULLTEXT | SPATIAL] INDEX index_name
    [index_type]
    ON tbl_name (key_part,...)
    [index_option]
    [algorithm_option | lock_option] ...

key_part: {col_name [(length)] | (expr)} [ASC | DESC]

index_option:
    KEY_BLOCK_SIZE [=] value
  | index_type
  | WITH PARSER parser_name
  | COMMENT 'string'
  | {VISIBLE | INVISIBLE}  -- Notice the option of VISIBLE / INVISIBLE

index_type:
  USING {BTREE | HASH}
```

However, this option of `{VISIBLE | INVISIBLE}` is not available in the **MySQL Server 5.7**. From [Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html):

```
CREATE [UNIQUE | FULLTEXT | SPATIAL] INDEX index_name
    [index_type]
    ON tbl_name (key_part,...)
    [index_option]
    [algorithm_option | lock_option] ...

key_part:
    col_name [(length)] [ASC | DESC]

index_option:
    KEY_BLOCK_SIZE [=] value
  | index_type
  | WITH PARSER parser_name
  | COMMENT 'string'

index_type:
    USING {BTREE | HASH}
```