# Adding Auto Increment and Unique to Table ID Failing

Tags: mysql, xampp, mariadb, mysql-workbench

I am using mysql workbench to alter a table, and I have never had trouble with this before. I am trying to alter my table to have a unique table ID that auto increments. I get the following from my error screen:

```
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
Executing:
ALTER TABLE `madewix5_lindsey_website_data`.`products` 
CHANGE COLUMN `product_id` `product_id` INT(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `product_id_UNIQUE` (`product_id` ASC) VISIBLE;
;

ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `madewix5_lindsey_website_data`.`products` 
CHANGE COLUMN `product_id` `product_id` INT(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `product_id_UNIQUE` (`product_id` ASC) VISIBLE
```

It looks good to me syntactically, so I am not sure why it is saying there is an issue. There is ONE row of data in the table.

**EDIT**
According to `mysql --version`, my xampp server is currently using version `Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.36-MariaDB, for Win32 (AMD64)` so the suggested duplicate in the comments probably isn't applicable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Workbench: Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'VISIBLE' at line 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52785125/mysql-workbench-error-in-query-1064-syntax-error-near-visible-at-line-1)

Comment: Also check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52915425/2469308 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/53041025/2469308

Comment: not applicable, I am using MySQL ver 15

Comment: There is no version 15 in MySQL. You are using Mariadb instead. I am not sure that Mariadb supports `VISIBLE` keyword yet. Just remove that word after the `add unique index ..` part and check again.

Comment: I will try, but I hope that is understandable why when I saw those answers I didn't think it was applicable

Comment: Removing Visible worked in this case. To clarify, this is also applicable to Maria-DB on an up to date version of xampp as of 11/24/2018

Comment: Do you already have a `PRIMARY KEY` on that table?  If not, shouldn't you be making `product_id` the PK?

Comment: Yes I did make the primary key, I simply am making the key more robust

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the help in the comments, the suggestion from other answers has been given but to clarify, on the specific case of an XAMPP server that is up to date with its Maria-DB software, the word "visible" may not be supported at this time. Removing the work "visible" allowed the script to run and added the unique and auto increment attributes to the primary key.

```
ALTER TABLE `madewix5_lindsey_website_data`.`products` 
CHANGE COLUMN `product_id` `product_id` INT(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `product_id_UNIQUE` (`product_id` ASC);
```